# Core Graphics- get window occlusion state with Quartz/CGWindow system

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, appkit

I am creating a MacOS applet that wants to detect the occlusion state of windows not specific to my current application. Since I cannot get NSWindow objects of other applications, I will need to use the Core Graphics layer to detect and manipulate windows. This means I won't have access to AppKit's NSWindow property "occlusionState" and need to find an alternative way to determine the window's occlusion state.

Right now I'm retrieving a list of CGWindows with the CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo method. I have taken a look at the documentation and see there are a few constants that I could potentially use (kCGWindowLayer, kCGWindowIsOnscreen... which always returns true even if windows are occluded) if I need to find a workaround, but I was curious if you all knew of a better way to do this or if there's some property that I'm not familiar with.  If not, is there an example somewhere of an app trying to do this?

```
let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(type, kCGNullWindowID) as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]

  for entry  in windowList!
  {
  //Get a list of all windows that are visible on the screen ...
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a way to to this via Core Graphics API? Even a negative response is appreciated. Regards!